# discord.py How to make a roll dice command

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello guys i'm coding a Discord bot in Python and i wanted to code a roll dice command. And i think im doing something wrong. Here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def rolldice(ctx):
    dice4 = ["1","2","3","4"]
    dice6 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
    dice8 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
    dice10 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    dice12 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
    dice20 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
    
    message = await ctx.send("Choose a number:\n**4**, **6**, **8**, **10**, **12**, **20** ")
    
    def check4(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.content == "4"

    try:
        await client.wait_for('message', check=check4, timeout=30.0)
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        time.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"**{random.choice(dice4)}**")
        
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't answer in **30** second!")

    def check6(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.content == "6"

    try:
        await client.wait_for('message', check=check6, timeout=30.0)
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        time.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"**{random.choice(dice6)}**")
        
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't answer in **30** second!")
    
    def check8(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.content == "8"

    try:
        await client.wait_for('message', check=check8, timeout=30.0)
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        time.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"**{random.choice(dice8)}**")
        
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't answer in **30** second!")

    def check10(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.content == "10"

    try:
        await client.wait_for('message', check=check10, timeout=30.0)
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        time.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"**{random.choice(dice10)}**")
        
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't answer in **30** second!")

    def check12(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.content == "12"

    try:
        await client.wait_for('message', check=check12, timeout=30.0)
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        time.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"**{random.choice(dice12)}**")
        
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't answer in **30** second!")

    def check20(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.content == "20"

    try:
        await client.wait_for('message', check=check20, timeout=30.0)
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        time.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"**{random.choice(dice20)}**")
        
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't answer in **30** second!")
```

When i type the command and select number 4 my command does works but when i try another number, for an example 6, it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it checks for **4** first, then **6**, and so on... Even after you send **4**, it'll check for **6**, **8** and so on.. And when you send **6**, it'll check for **4** first, then **6** and so on.. Why don't you try something like this instead:

```py
@client.command()
async def rolldice(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Choose a number:\n**4**, **6**, **8**, **10**, **12**, **20** ")
    
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author

    try:
        message = await client.wait_for("message", check = check, timeout = 30.0)
        m = message.content

        if m != "4" and m != "6" and m != "8" and m != "10" and m != "12" and m != "20":
            await ctx.send("Sorry, invalid choice.")
            return
        
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        time.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"**{random.randint(1, int(m))}**")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't respond in **30** seconds.")
```

**Note:** I recommend using `await asyncio.sleep(1)` instead of `time.sleep(1)`. That way other commands will still be functional. Remember to import `asyncio` in this case.